# Is this a dependent or an independent clause?

Tags: grammar

This is the second half of a sentence that uses a semi-colon, and it appeared incorrect to me because I thought this part was a dependent clause. But I am not sure.

> They launched into a war that shaped America to be what it is today; **a strong powerful country, who will fight for their rights.**

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided the first part of the sentence as well.

Comment: They launched into a war that shaped America to be what it is today; a strong powerful country, who will fight for their rights.

Comment: It's not a clause, but a NP. The semicolon should be a colon.

Comment: Yes, because the second part is a dependent clause, right?

Comment: *who will &c* is a dependent clause, but it modifies *a ... country*, which is a noun phrase.

Comment: Ok, could the second part stand on its own as a sentence? It seems incomplete to me.

Comment: It cannot stand on its own as a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the full sentence would help. Lacking that,

"a strong powerful country, who will fight for their rights." is not a dependent clause; it is a noun phrase (a strong powerful country) which is modified by a relative clause (who will fight for their rights) (thank you StoneyB). Still, it does not express a complete thought.

Therefore, it should not follow a semi colon, for semicolons join two independent clauses (when they're not separating items in a list that already involve commas.)

It would be a **wrong** use of a semi colon here:

*I love Liechtenstein; a strong powerful country, who will fight for their rights.*

**correct** (grammatically):

*I love Liechtenstein; **it is** a strong powerful country, who(which?) will fight for their rights.*

source: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/44/

Comment: I think not. It's not any sort of clause; it's a noun phrase which is modified by a relative clause. The subject of *will fight* is *who*, which refers to the preceding noun phrase.

Comment: Susan, @Stoney is correct. “a strong powerful country, who will fight for their rights” is not a clause. It is a noun phrase with an embedded clause. “Who will fight for their rights” is a dependent clause, but for the whole thing to be a clause, it would have to have a verb outside the embedded clause as well. (That does not make what you say about semicolons incorrect—a dangling noun phrase should no more follow a semicolon than a dependent clause should.)

Comment: No need for apologies: that one point aside, it's a good answer. In fact your **correct** version anticipates JBJ's comment about needing a verb. The thing to do now is to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

A semi colon is the wrong symbol to use here. a colon is the correct symbol. Also, "country" should be considered singular and "who will fight for its rights" is correct, not "theirs."

Comment: However, the first word of the quotation is *they*, presumably referring to the early settlers, so changing *their* to *its* would be a mistake.